# How can I change the column widths of the file list in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, user-interface

How can I change the column widths of the file list in Google Drive? I see that I can change the width of the folder hierarchy by dragging the vertical divider in the left frame, but the file parameter columns (name, owner, last modified, file size) seem to not be manually adjustable.  If I resize the entire browser window the columns auto-adjust their width, but I'm interested in manually overriding the default widths for a given browser window size according to my preference, specifically so I can see the full filename without hovering the mouse.

[image: Google Drive file list]

Comment: this worked for me reasonably for me with the same problem... first click on the Details button (circled "i" upper right), then the columns spread across the page and get wider, display more content including at least most of the filenames (reasonable length ones at least).

Answer (score 1):

Normally we can design the table cells with two ways

**- Fixed**

**- Resizable**

We can able to resize the width of the column only if it designed with resizable attribute and query in the code looks like

```
$('.classOfTables').flexigrid({height:'auto',striped:false});
```

If it was designed with fixed table attribute then it is not possible to adjust the column width. Therefore, we suspect it is not possible to change the column(Google drive column) width.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the width is fixed and the only option is going to the "cogwheel" settings option and choose "comfortable" or "cozy" or "compact" - and this will result in more or less info to appear in the fixed-width columns... Not a solution, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Firefox and a neat solution is to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> option. This neatly resizes the columns while expanding the size of the font.

Comment: What does Ctrl Shift + do? I'm not seeing it on the Firefox list of keyboard shortcuts, which makes me wonder if you meant Ctrl + which is Zoom In. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly